# Translate text with gettext and include url

Tags: php, str-replace, gettext

I am using gettext to translate some part of my wordpress website (using php snippets). I was wondering if it is possible to include an url when the function return the value. I am not familiar with php but this is what I tried :

```
add_filter('gettext', 'url_to_My_Dashbord', 999, 3 );
function url_to_My_Dashbord( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
$translated = str_ireplace( 'My Dashboard', 'Tableau de bord', $translated );
return '<a href="http://google.fr">'.$translated.'</a>';}
```

But unfortunately it is not working. May I ask you for your support ?

**EDIT**

Thanks to your comments I tried that :

```
add_filter('gettext', 'url_to_My_Dashbord', 999, 3 );
function url_to_My_Dashbord( $translated, $text, $domain ) {
$translated = str_ireplace( 'My Dashboard', '<a href="http://google.fr">Tableau de bord</a>', $translated );
return $translated}
```

But it does not work either, the translated text (i.e. Tableau de bord) is not visible

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: By not working, I mean that the url "http:// ..." is showing up everywhere there is text but not in the translated text

Comment: Why should it occur **in** the word if you wrap the whole translated text in the link?

Comment: @Nico `return '<a href="http://google.fr">'.$translated.'</a>';` URL will be around your translated texts not in translated texts, you need to implod translated texts and include URL in

Comment: @Dilek around whatever translated texts, right ? So it explains why it show up everywhere :)

Comment: @Nico yes, exactly! there are several ways to do what you want, First translate text, than implode all translated texts and put them in url. so they will look like tags, or you can just link to all texts translated. I saw a nice article about creating tags in php in stackoverfllow earlier. would help you.